# Keycloak getting config from admin console

Tags: java, docker, keycloak

I have created config in keycloak by overriding `getConfigProperties` method of
`AuthenticatorFactory` interface.

```
@Override
public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
    final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<>();
    ProviderConfigProperty property = new ProviderConfigProperty();
    property.setName("external.url");
    property.setLabel("External service base url");
    property.setType(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE);
    property.setHelpText("Base url for the external service base url");
    configProperties.add(property);

    return configProperties;
}
```

Now im trying to access the config set in admin console in `init()` method

```
@Override
public void init(Config.Scope config) {
    super.init(config);
    url = config.get("external.url");
}
```

but its not the case as this takes the config file, not the admin console's config. How can I access the config from the admin console so that i can change values in runtime without rerunning whole docker process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Authenticator` implementation using `AuthenticationFlowContext`:

Both of these methods expose it:

```java
void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context);
void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context);
```

```java
final Map<String, String> config = context.getAuthenticatorConfig().getConfig();
```